# C# IO Stream not working like expected

Tags: c#, io

I have this piece of code here:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt");
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line == textBox1.Text)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line == textBox2.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Logged in! Welcome " + textBox1.Text);
                    new Form2().Show();
                    this.Hide();
                    LoginSucces = true;
                }

            }

        }
        sr.Close();
        if (LoginSucces == false) MessageBox.Show("Login Failed :(");
    }
```

And it reads from this text:

AverageJavaGuy

Password

Chezzy

Password

The problem is that it doesnt work!

When I type in:

textBox1 = Chezzy.

textBox2 = Password.

it doesnt work...
it only works for AverageJavaGuy.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checking what the values are line by line?

Comment: “It doesnt work!” is not a question. You have to tell us what you expected to happen, what happened, and why you think the two are different. Note that your code will compare every line against `textBox1.Text` until it matches; only then will it compare against `textBox2.Text`. Is that what you want?

Comment: `while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)` raises a few red flags for me. Far too much side effects in this line for a loop condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dictionary<string, string> userPass_dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // add this at class level
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt"))
        {
            string line = "";
            string line2 = "";
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                line2 = sr.ReadLine();
                userPass_dict.Add(line, line2);

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So it works for the first login/password, but not the second ?

Have you checked your textfile ? 
Isn't the problem related to the dot beside "Chezzy" (in you post!) ?

Try to add "Console.WriteLine" or use debugger to fix your code and see what happens it the loop.

Also, I think the inner " sr.ReadLine();" in the loop may cause unexpected "shifting" according to the textfile content, use it carefully...

Comment: I dont think since it will work... it needs that sr.ReadLine();

Comment: StuartLC answered to that. My advices remain the same : use the debugger, check your input file.

Comment: When i try it for the first time after launching the chezzy name doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

move line = sr.ReadLine(); to the outside the if statement

Comment: Would you mind to explain why would such change help?

Comment: That would brake the logic

Comment: the logic doesn't work as it is...maybe read the usernames and passwords in and store them in a dictionary...then compare the textbox contents to the dictionary

Comment: How would i do that? like do the same but then in an array?